# Use sign in with Google via REST API

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am building a project using passport and sign in with Google to authenticate user. I use REST api to communicate with backend server and use axios to get data on frontend. The problem is i can't redirect to callback api and get this message on frontend `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`. When i try it on browser, it runs normally. How can i fix it? I also think about using sign in with Google on frontend.

Comment: You need to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to include your app's url or `*`, check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: I know but this api is belong to google not mine. So i can't do that